# How to delete multiple folders in parallel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, concurrency

I have two directories on the same level and I can do:

```
rm -rf dir1/; rm -rf dir2/
```

but they will be running sequentially, how could I remove them in parallel? is there a generic solution too which allows me to extend to many folders?

**Update**

The directories may be deeply nested containing other directories and so on.

Comment: Why don't you use `&`? `rm -rf dir1/& rm -rf dir2/`. Thus bash will not wait for the first command (deleting dir1) to start the second one.

Comment: I'm not sure, why someone downvotes this. It is a good question althoúgh the given example is really weak. See me answer for a cool approach using gnu parallel, whenever you want to go cool parallelizing stuff in bash. HTH

Comment: @tink, I think you're probably right. But I've been using this approach (doing something in parallel in bash) more than once when scripting stuff. It may be a philosophical question wether simple shell scripting is to be considered coding or not. I'd say yes, it is. But the ops question itself is somewhat far away from this.

Comment: @vivek, can you explain the nature of the files inside those directories. Do you have huge no of files ? huge no of sub directories ? huge sized files etc ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run the commands in background

```
rm -rf dir &; rm -rf dir2 &;
```

syntax

```
long_command with arguments > redirection &
```

you can capture any messages by redirecting the command output to a file.

This links will help ==> http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

#### Edit :

The question title & given example gives an impression like the issue is very small. 
But an added bounty showing the seriousness of the issue.

It would be better if you specify the nature of your files. However, I am providing some split based deletion which can implemented as parallel executions
You can try below options based on your requirement.

deleting files by size

```
find /yourpath/folder1 -size +1048576 -exec rm -f {} \; &
find /yourpath/folder2 -size +1048576 -exec rm -f {} \; &
```

deleting files by extension

find extensions by using below command

```
ls -l /yourpath/folder1 | awk '{print $9}' | awk -F. '{print $(NF)}' |sort |uniq
```

you may get result like

```
.txt
.log
.tmp
.zip
```

now, delete the files based on extensions

```
find yourpath/folder1 -name '*.txt' -exec rm {} \; &
find yourpath/folder1 -name '*.tmp' -exec rm {} \; &
find yourpath/folder1 -name '*.log' -exec rm {} \; &
find yourpath/folder2 -name '*.txt' -exec rm {} \; &
find yourpath/folder2 -name '*.tmp' -exec rm {} \; &
find yourpath/folder2 -name '*.log' -exec rm {} \; &
```

deleting files by modified time

below command tries to delete files older than 5 days.

```
find yourpath/folder1 -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

OR

```
find yourpath/folder2 -mtime +5 |xargs rm
```

deleting folder & it's sub folders including it's files

```
find foldername -exec rm -rf {} \; &
```

[image: example folder & sub folder structure]

Comment: No need of a ; after the &. In case he has many directory, a for loop can do the trick: `for d in dir*; do rm $d& done`

Answer (score 11):

Just in case you want to do more than removing directories in parallel, you can do a lot of parallel fancy stuff with [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). As it often is not a base utility in distributions, you may need to install it using your favourite package manager, e.g. `apt-get install parallel`.

But then, you can do cool stuff like this, say you run 4 parallel processes, want to show the progress, no nag notice and let in parallel run a sleep command waiting for 5s, 10s, 15s, 20s each.

```
$ parallel -j 4 --progress --no-notice sleep ::: 5 10 15 20 

Computers / CPU cores / Max jobs to run
1:local / 4 / 4

Computer:jobs running/jobs completed/%of started jobs/Average seconds to complete
local:0/4/100%/5.0s
```

Your example would be running like this:

```
$ parallel --no-notice rm -rf ::: dir1 dir2 dir3
```

Feel free to consult the [fine tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

Comment: I used `find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type f | parallel --jobs 0 -a - rm {}; find dir1 dir2 dir3 | parallel --jobs 0 -a - rm -rf {}`

Answer (score 2):

I had to clean up some folders in /media as fast as possible.
The following command was able to delete 9T of data on each of the 80 disks in roughly 5mn

```
$ sudo find /media -maxdepth 2 -name "data-8" -type d | while read folder; do eval "sudo rm -rf ${folder} &"; done
```

This kicked 80 parallel `rm -rf` in the background

Comment: Just remember to be extra careful when using `rm -rf` with `sudo`.

Answer (score -2):

#### 2020 Update

If anyone returns here for the same solution. I suppose it's much easier to do it like this:

1. go inside the folder where you have other subfolders or file you wanna delete in bulk. Lets call it `target_folder` so

   ```
    cd target_folder
   ```
2. type `ls -la` and enter

   ```
    [home@target_folder]$ ls -la
   ```
3. It will list all subfolders and files. Now last step. Type:

   ```
    [home@target_folder]$ rm -rf {folder1,folder2,folder3,so on...}
   ```

Just double click on the file name and make a right-click to paste and that's about it..once you are done listing all file name ..press enter and voila..All folders or files wil be deleted.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to delete in parallel.

Answer (score -2):

Create a list of folders in plane text file (i.e. list_delfolders). then run in the for loop or in while loop.
$ cat list_delfolders | while read ids; do rm -rf "$ids";done

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to delete in parallel.

Answer (score -2):

Very simple !!!

rm -r folder1 folder2 folder3

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

Simple solution: 
go to the destination folder and do rm -r 'some regex' ,the folder names that matches with the regex will get deleted.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to delete in parallel.